# batch class for opportunity records to send an email that the opportunity closing date is tommorow

Tags: batch

```
global class sendemail implements Database.Batchable <sobject> {

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

String Query;

Query = 'SELECT Name,Id From Opportunities WHERE CloseDate = createddate+1';

return Database.getquerylocator(Query);

 }

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Opportunities> opplist) {

for(Opportunities opp :opplist){

       opp.CloseDate = 'createddate+1'; 

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        email.setToAddresses(new String[] {'nihar.annamaneni@gmail.com'});

        email.setSubject('opportunity closed date');

        email.setPlainTextBody('Dear user, Your opportunity  closed date is tommorow');

        emails.add(email);

        }

        Messaging.sendEmail(emails);

        update opplist;

        }

global void finish(database.BatchableContext bc){
        }
}
```

Comment: Right now, you have only made a statement. I don't know what question you're trying to ask. Please read [ask], and then [edit] your question to include more details (comments are restricted in length and formatting, and are best thought of as temporary, so it's better to [edit]). One other thing, we only know about your specific situation/problem if you tell us (using words). Statements like "it doesn't work" aren't helpful because we don't know what "it" is, or how it's supposed to work. Bottom line: Include as many details as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the date variable and then use it in your query.

Also there are some other mistake in your code.

- Instead of Opportunities you need to pass correct api name Opportunity in all places
- You don't need to update the close date as it is already tomorrow.
- You don't need to declare the `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` List

---

```
global class sendemail implements Database.Batchable < sobject > {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

        String Query;
        Date dt = date.today().addDays(1);
        Query = 'SELECT Name,Id From Opportunity WHERE CloseDate =: dt ';
        return Database.getquerylocator(Query);

    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List < Opportunity > opplist) {

        List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > emails = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > ();
        for (Opportunity opp: opplist) {

            // opp.CloseDate = 'createddate+1'; 

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            email.setToAddresses(new String[] {
                'nihar.annamaneni@gmail.com'
            });

            email.setSubject('opportunity closed date');

            email.setPlainTextBody('Dear user, Your opportunity '+opp.name+' closed date is tommorow');

            emails.add(email);

        }

        Messaging.sendEmail(emails);

        // update opplist;

    }

    global void finish(database.BatchableContext bc) {}
}
```

Comment: But i am facing error :  Class sendemail must implement the method: void Database.Batchable<SObject>.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List<SObject>) and i have to send mutiple users at a time

Comment: @nihar check my updated answer.

Comment: with the help of your updated answer i am not able to get any mail to user the opportunity close date is tommorow and i have to sent multiple users and multiple records at a time

Comment: @nihar I just run this code in my org and get the email. Make sure you have correct data in your org.

Comment: what is the closed date on your record

Comment: @nihar its tomorrow.

Comment: i am happy with your but i dont know what is the problem i am facing to get the output i mean mails to user and owner and my closed date is tomorrow in record.........

Comment: i am happy to inform you that my problem is solved thanks for your help but only one change i need is how to show opportunity name in the mail example : which mail is reagding to which opportunity record

Comment: @nihar check my updated answer.

Comment: i need your help but only one change i need is how to show opportunity record link in the mail example : which mail is reagding to which opportunity record – record link

Comment: @nihar you can create the link as `url.getBaseurl().toexternalform()+'/'+opp.Id`

Comment: where can i add this line in above code

Comment: @nihar in the end of body.

Comment: the above code is sending mail to only to one user but how can i send mail to another user also

Comment: @nihar it would be better if you post a new question instead of asking in comments.

Comment: i cant post another question for 6 days is not allowing me to post so i am asking you

Answer (score 0):

## Email Users, not Emails

Emails are limited to 1,000 per day, but you can email as many users as you like without using your daily limits.

## Query Users

Since you're interested in notifying users, you should start from the User table, not the Opportunity table. This also limits the number of emails the user may receive to just one, no matter how many opportunities they have.

## Date Literal

In this case, you can use the literal TOMORROW to make your code easier to read.

## Use Inline Queries When Possible

Do not use a String for your query when you can help it, as it is naturally error-prone, and easy to make typos that you cannot detect until you try to run your code.

## Suggested Updates

```
public class sendemail implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Name FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND Id IN
                                         (SELECT OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate = TOMORROW)]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, User[] scope) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT COUNT(Id) sum, OwnerId Id
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE OwnerId = :scope AND CloseDate = TOMORROW
            GROUP BY OwnerId
        ]);
        for(User record: scope) {
            if(results.containsKey(record.Id)) {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                message.setSubject('You have opportunities closing tomorrow.');
                message.setPlainTextBody(record.Name+', you have '+results.get(record.Id)+' opportunities closing tomorrow.');
                message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                message.setTargetObjectId(record.Id);
                messages.add(message);
            }
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the code when i am using the above code i am not getting emails to users or owners

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Do you have any opportunities closing tomorrow? Are those users active?

Comment: no errors yes i have opportunities closing tommorow and my users are active

Comment: @nihar You'll need to read the logs, then. This code should work fine as-is.

Comment: i am happy to inform you that my problem is solved thanks for your help but only one change i need is how to show opportunity name in the mail example : which mail is reagding to which opportunity record –